# NFT (Rarible) double item

Tags: blockchain, nft

I’m new in NFT and Rarible as NFT sell point.

I have enter one of my images to sell, but after 2 days of pending signing contract in my Coinbase  Wallet, I received message “failed“.

I have started all over again (for same image) and then second attempt passed and everything was fine, but then I noticed that it has took Etherum also for the first failed attempt and put same image on sell.

So, I was charged $120 in whole for miners and gas, so what now?

Is there possibility to change image in that first contract?

What is “Transfer token”? Can I do anything here and not loose $60?

As I see, this is Coinbase Wallet error, there was obviously end of signing attempts, because it stop spinning and I received Failed message.
Why did it then charge me anyway? Or this will try endlessly (even if I got failed message) until contract pass?

Thanks in advance for helping me here.

Comment: What are the transaction hashes? Can you check what was the result in a block explorer like Etherscan? Unfortunately even if a transaction has failed you have to pay the transactions fees, that are quite high these days. Did you try to contact Rarible support?

Comment: No, I did not try to contact them, should I? Will it change anything?

Comment: Without the transactions hashes is hard to know what happened exactly. From your description it appears the first transaction didn't failed but it was pending for so long that the wallet show it as failed. When you send the second transaction the gas price had lowered enough that the first transaction was also confirmed. In Ethereum a transaction is valid until is is mined or replaced. You already paid $120 contacting Rarible support costs nothing and they might provide some help to avoid future mistakes.